# Injective resolution of the ring of entire functions

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, cv.complex-variables, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be the ring of entire functions on $\mathbb{C}$. I heard that the concrete value of the global dimension of the ring depends on continuum hypothesis.
I would think that the injective dimension of the regular module $R$ should coincide with the global dimension for this ring but I'm not sure.

> Question: Can one write down an explicit (minimal) injective resolution of the regular module $R$? How does it look like in case it is possible?